# ezPlot overlapping error bar and data

Tags: r

I am using ezPlot from the ez package in R to plot results of a mixed within and between-ss design. The data  point from the two groups I have overlap so that I would like to jitter both the data point and associated error bar.

```
data<-structure(list(Sub = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("WW", "XX", "YY", 
"ZZ"), class = "factor"), DepVar = c(0.67, 0.35, 0.09, 0.2, 0.19, 
0.13, 0.45, 0.23, 0.08, 0.32, 0.17, 0.18, 0.67, 0.36, 0.55, 0.4, 
0.37, 0.05, 0.26, 0.11, 0.08, 0.46, 0.29, 0.18, 0.16, 0, 0.38, 
0.22, 0.08, 0.1, 0.54, 0.17, 0.07, 0.38, 0.75, 0.87, 0.27, 0.57, 
0.31, 0.28, 0.07, 0.12, 0.75, 0.33, 0.23, 0.33, 0.26, 0.18), 
Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
Con = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sub", "DepVar", 
"Group", "Con"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))

ezPlot( data,
    dv = .(DepVar),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(Con),  
    between=.(Group),
    split=.(Group),
    do_bars=TRUE,
    type = 2, 
    x = .(Con))
```

[image]

A non elegant trick is so set scale-color manual white so that the underlying data points disappear and then using geom-point position dodge(0.4))

```
ezPlot( data,
    dv = .(DepVar),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(Con),  
    between=.(Group),
    split=.(Group),
    do_bars=TRUE,
    type = 2, 
    x = .(Con))+ 
      scale_color_manual(values=c("white", "white"))+
      geom_point(aes(fill=Group), color="black", pch= 21, size= 3, position=position_dodge(0.4))+
      geom_line(aes(group = Group),  lty = 3, lwd = 1.3, color='black')
```

[image]

however, I would like to have the error bar plotted and I don't know how to achieve this or if other workarounds are possible. I would like to stick to ezplot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use set `print_code = TRUE`, to produce data to be plotted, as well as the `ggplot` code:

```
library(ggplot2)
stats <- ezPlot( data,
    dv = .(DepVar),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(Con),  
    between=.(Group),
    split=.(Group),
    do_bars=TRUE,
    type = 2, 
    x = .(Con),
    print_code = TRUE)
```

Then, manually modify the code to add `position = position_dodge(0.4)` to each geom, then run the `ggplot` code.

A more efficient way to do the same thing would be to `capture.output` the code as a character vector, use `gsub` to add `position = position_dodge(0.4)`, then `eval(parse(text = ...))` the modified code:

```
gg_code <- capture.output(stats <- ezPlot( data,
    dv = .(DepVar),
    wid = .(Sub),  # subject
    within = .(Con),  
    between=.(Group),
    split=.(Group),
    do_bars=TRUE,
    type = 2, 
    x = .(Con),
    print_code = TRUE))
gg_code <- gsub("alpha", "position = position_dodge(0.4), alpha", gg_code)
eval(parse(text = paste(gg_code, collapse = "")))
```

Output:

[image]